# TypeError: execute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'

Tags: python, typeerror

Apologies if this question has been asked before.
I am attempting to create a function that returns the output from another function with the arguments func (The function to execute) and args (The argument for the function).
Annoyingly I keep getting an error.

```
TypeError: execute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'
```

I am not sure as to what the issue is as I can see no error with the definition or call for the function. If it helps here is the definition;

```
def execute(func, args):
 return func(args)
```

And the line where I call the function:

```
print(function)
print(argument)
execute((function, argument))
```

The full output is:

```
print
Hello world
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 267, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(options.target, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 268, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\willd\source\repos\code executer\code_executer.py", line 52, in <module>
    execute((function, argument))
TypeError: execute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'
```

If it helps I am using Microsoft visual studio 2019 community.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: execute(function, argument)

Comment: `(function, argument)` is one thing - a tuple with two values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the variables as a tuple which gets counted as a single item. Your correct way to call the function would be:

`execute(function, argument)`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise I had added a second pair of brackets. Thank you again!

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer so that this question is resolved!

Answer (score 0):

you're giving python only one argument, which is a tuple formed by the parantheses.
To call execute properly you need to remove the parantheses, because python interprets these as a tuple.
A tuple is non-mutable.

`execute(function, arguments)` calls execute with 2 parameters,
equivalent to `execute(func=function, args=arguments)`

`execute((function, arguments))` calls 'execute' with only 1 parameter.
which is equivalent to `execute(func=(function, arguments))` and missing 'arguments'.

Recommendations:
Look at partials if you want to avoid passing arguments.

If function has multiple positional arguments, you should change your code to something like, otherwise you'll run into the same problem again.:

```py
def execute(function, *args):
    return function(*args)
```